# CiviCRM profile "used for" options are not allowing a CiviContribute option on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, profile

I'm running CiviCRM Version 5.13.5 on WordPress 5.2.2

When I set up on staging, I used CiviCRM Version 5.13.4, and the various Profile options were available, including : 
Used For    Standalone Form or Directory Search Views [ x ] User Registration [ x ] User Account [ x ] soft_credit [ x ] CiviContribute [ x ] on_behalf

However, now that I'm setting up on live with Version 5.13.5, my only available options are:
Used For    Standalone Form or Directory Search Views [ x ] User Registration [ x ] User Account

Any help for why the Contribution options are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it seems a little weird. It seems to get those options to show you need to first create a contribution page and check the options related to those. So:

For soft_credit, you need to have an existing contribution page with the `Honoree Section Enabled` checked.

For on_behalf, you need to have an existing contribution page with the `Allow individuals to contribute and / or signup for membership on behalf of an organization` checked.

For civicontribute to show, you need to have an existing contribution page where the profiles tab has already been set to use a profile.

But in any case they seem to be just visual indicators that indicate that you have a page that uses it.

Comment: Okay, so that explains a lot of things that I was trying to understand about profiles but couldn't find mentioned in the documentation. Since I was working on a live site, I didn't want to mess anything up and was proceeding with caution. But this was very helpful, and I will forge ahead!

Comment: Great! Forge away!